# Google API - How to create a link to a map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Can anyone pls advise on how to create a link to a google map created via javascript? Can this even be done?

```
var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
  zoom: 8
});
```

I have a normal link but want it to go to the location on the map i have created in my javascript.

http://www.google.com/maps/place/49.46800006494457,17.11514008755796

Comment: What do you mean by "create a link to a google map created by javascript"?  Something like [this "link to" functionality](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_linktomap.html?id=Marker%20Two&lat=43.761177&lng=-77.909033&zoom=7&type=m)?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.com/maps/@-34.397,150.644,8z

lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644, zoom: 8